# Is that possible to integrate the FacebookSDK inside the custom framework

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, frameworks

Is that possible to integrate the FacebookSDK inside the custom framework?. I have created the custom framework and working perfectly as expected. Now i trying to integrate the FacebookSDK inside the created custom framework. How can i achieve this?

update: i working in creating a framework, which support facebook login and signup.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the Facebook SDK... You question is quite vague... please elaborate.

Comment: i need to include facebook login and signup via created custom framework.